# The list of my associated accounts on the mobile interface just says "Stack Overflow" over and over

Tags: bug, status-completed, mobile-web

Screenshot:

[image]

It's like this on my user profile on every site, no matter whether or not I'm logged in. The links lead to the correct sites (as indicated by their icons); the text just says "Stack Overflow".

I'm on an iPhone 4S with iOS 5.0.1, if it makes any difference.

Comment: +1 This is hilarious.

Comment: I'm seeing this too, for any account

Comment: Well, by golly, it does it on an android too!

Comment: It's an issue with the mobile version of the site. I am seeing it too after switching my user-agent to a phone's.

Comment: It's Stack Overflows all the way down.

Comment: Would be nice to have it all summed together as well :)

Comment: Suddenly the graphs in [this earlier post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114419/is-stack-exchanges-qa-format-particularly-well-suited-to-programmers) all make sense.

Comment: I knew this whole "Stack Exchange" fad would play out eventually, and we'd be back to 59 flavors of Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was an undocumented feature, but since you didn't like it, we'll remove it in the next build.

Comment: Can we keep it as a toggle feature?